# Scala convert Future[Option[Account]] to Future[Either[String, Option[Account]]]

Tags: scala, future

I have the following methods that return futures:

```
db.find(uuid, accountName): Future[Option[Account]]

db.add(uuid, account): Future[Option[Account]]
```

I want to write a program that finds a user in the database using a future.
If not, a user entry should be added to the database.
In either case, I want to get back a `Future[Either[String, Option[Account]]]` object.
I am getting a compiler error when I write the following:

```
def add(uuid: UUID, account: Account): Future[Either[String, Option[Account]]] =
    db.find(userId, account.name).map {
        case None =>    
            db.add(userId.uuid, account).map(Right(_))
        case Some(existAccount) =>
            Left(s"Account already exist $existAccount")
    }
```

**Edit:**
This code can`t compile with error:

```
Error:(77, 41) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Right[Nothing,Option[Account]]]
 required: Either[String,Option[Account]]
        db.add(userId, account).map(Right(_))
                                        ^
```

**Resolved:**
Solution is:

```
object Test extends App {
  import concurrent._
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits._
  import duration.Duration._
  type Account = String
  val found = """(.+)\1""".r
  def find(name: String) = name match {
    case found(_*) => Future(Option(name))
    case _         => Future(None)
  }
  def add(account: Account) = Future(Option(account * 2))

  def f(account: Account): Future[Either[String, Option[Account]]] = {
    find(account) flatMap {
      case None => add(account) map (Right(_))
      case Some(x) => Future successful Left(s"already $account")
    }
  }
  Console println Await.result(f("bob"), Inf)
  Console println Await.result(f("bobbob"), Inf)
}
```

Comment: This code looks OK on the surface. Are you getting an error?

Comment: It's not possible to help you without an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: His code does not compile because he's mapping a future into a future of futures. He should use `flatMap` instead. Although it might be a bit unclear, this is a valid question and should be reopened.

Comment: try:     db.find(userId, account.name).flatMap{
      case None               => db.add(userId, account).map(Right[String, Option[Account]](_))
      case Some(existAccount) => Future(Left(s"Account already exist $existAccount"))
    }

Comment: further, check whether you actually want: db.add(userId, account).map {
      case ao@Some(_) => Right(ao)
      case None       => Left(s"Account already exist $account")
    }